# prevent sql injection in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

I am using the following query to find nearest locations google maps. Is it immune to the Sql injection. If not can anyone help me to get rid of it.

```
AlphaCourses.find_by_sql("SELECT *,(  6371 * acos( cos( radians( #{@latitude} ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( #{@longitude} ) ) + sin( radians( #{@latitude} ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM alpha_courses HAVING distance <= #{@radius} ORDER BY distance LIMIT 200")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the second example here - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql . Avoid interpolating the attributes directly.

Comment: Thanks for your replay I tried like this AlphaCourses.find_by_sql("SELECT *,(  6371 * acos( cos( radians( ? ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( ? ) ) + sin( radians( ? ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM alpha_courses HAVING distance <= #{@radius} ORDER BY distance LIMIT 200","#{@latitude}","#{@longitude}","#{@latitude}") but it shows some syntax error like (wrong no.of argumrnts 4 for 2)

Comment: See this syntax carefully - `Post.find_by_sql(["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id, start_date])`. Everything inside is in an array; you replace the model's fields by `?` and then sequentially write them after comma - here - `author_id`, `start_date`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions

> This code
>
> ```
> ....("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])
> ```
>
> is highly preferable to this code:
>
> ```
> ....("orders_count = #{params[:orders]}")
> ```
>
> because of argument safety. Putting the variable directly into the
>   conditions string will pass the variable to the database as-is. This
>   means that it will be an unescaped variable directly from a user who
>   may have malicious intent. If you do this, you put your entire
>   database at risk because once a user finds out he or she can exploit
>   your database they can do just about anything to it. Never ever put
>   your arguments directly inside the conditions string.

Apply this to your example!

Comment: But I tried in many ways use to use where clause but I failed to use. can you please apply where to my query @bjelli

Comment: it's not the where-clause that's important (I edited that out). what's important is using ? in your sql string.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861739/5783745) answer may also be useful