# Is ActiveRecord's "order" method vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4

I know it's not safe to use interpolated strings when calling `.where`.

e.g. this:

`Client.where("orders_count = #{params[:orders]}")`

should be rewritten as:

`Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])`

Is it safe to use interpolated strings when calling `.order`? If not, how should the following be rewritten?

`Client.order("#{some_value_1}, #{some_value_2}")`

Comment: In array
        .order("#{field} #{ordering}")

It works like a magic! Thx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes, ActiveRecord's “order” method *is* vulnerable to SQL injection.**

**No, it is *not* safe to use interpolated strings when calling `.order`.**

The above answers to my question have been confirmed by [Aaron Patterson](https://twitter.com/tenderlove/status/360436060154642432), who pointed me to http://rails-sqli.org/#order . From that page:

> Taking advantage of SQL injection in ORDER BY clauses is tricky, but a
>   CASE statement can be used to test other fields, switching the sort
>   column for true or false. While it can take many queries, an attacker
>   can determine the value of the field.

Therefore it's important to manually check anything going to `order` is safe; perhaps by using methods similar to @dmcnally's suggestions.

Thanks all.

Comment: Hey @Mike I asked a question on this because I failed to understand how it works. Can you help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630381/explain-how-order-clause-can-be-exploited-in-rails

Comment: I think rails checks that the column exists these days when passing a raw string. It's probably still a good idea to sanitize though since this could in theory be used for a DDOS attack if there is a large result set and you sort by something that doesn't have good indexing.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer is you need to sanitize your inputs.

If the strings you are planning to interpolate come from an untrusted source (e.g. web browser) then you need to first map them to trusted values.  You could do this via a hash:

```
# Mappings from known values to SQL
order_mappings = {
  'first_name_asc'  => 'first_name ASC',
  'first_name_desc' => 'first_name DESC',
  'last_name_asc'   => 'last_name ASC',
  'last_name_desc'  => 'last_name DESC',
}

# Ordering options passed in as an array from some source:
order_options = ['last_name_asc', 'first_name_asc']

# Map them to the correct SQL:
order = order_options.map{|o| order_mappings[o] }.compact.join(', ')
Client.order(order)
```

Comment: That's useful, thanks. My actual order query is more complex than the question and it takes arbitrary user input. Ideally, I want to use an array syntax like I would with `where`. In summary, are you saying I have to do the work myself? :)

Answer (score 2):

@Mike explanation is correct. @dmcnally workaround would work. I'm following in a slightly different path mentioned in [Railscast][1]  http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

In a nutshell, if you can construct a private method in the controller, in order to sanitize the user input:

1. Order by name of one your table columns:

   ```
       private 

       def sort_column
          Client.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "first_name"
       end
   ```
2. Order by other criteria, then use the whitelist construct such as below:

   ```
   def sort_direction
       %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
   end
   ```

And your controller method should then look like this:

```
    Client.all.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

Just anther way to Rome. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this!

```
# app/models/concern/ext_active_record.rb
module ExtActiveRecord
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        scope :sortable, -> (params) do
            return unless params[:sort_by] && params[:sort_dir]
            reorder("#{params[:sort_by]}" => "#{params[:sort_dir]}")
        end
    end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ExtActiveRecord
    # ....
end

# app/controllers/user_controller.rb
class UserController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.sortable(params).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per])
    end
end
```

Answer (score -4):

`Client.order("#{some_value_1}, #{some_value_2}")`

should be written as

```
order = sanitize_sql_array(['%s, %s', some_value_1, some_value_2])
Client.order(order)
```

Comment: That won't be safe Mike, create a dummy table you don't mind losing and do the following:

Client.order('id asc; drop table dummy;')

You might be surprised

Comment: You're right, Dave. `Model..send(:sanitize_sql_array, ['mike %s', '; DROP TABLE X']) => "mike ; DROP TABLE X"`. So how do we make it safe like we would with `where`?

Comment: @dmcnally: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement"

Comment: ActiveRecord didn't always use prepared statements, but @Dorian shows one of the benefits: even when no bind params are used, they do prevent running more than one query when you expect just one. (Unless it's sneaked in as a UNION or something.)