# SQL Injection and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is this safe from SQL injection:

```
Guest.where(:event_id => params[:id])
```

I am sending in `params[:id]` without doing any type of sanitization.

and in general, are all of those activerecord method safe? (like `where`, `joins`, etc..)

And if not, what is the best practise to be safe? Also, please is there any caveats/edge cases I should be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All of ActiveRecord's query-building methods, like `where`, `group`, `order`, and so on, are safe against SQL injection **AS LONG AS** you do not pass them raw SQL strings. This is vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
 Model.where("event_id = #{params[:id]}")
```

When you pass a string to a query-building method like that, the string will be inserted *directly* into the generated SQL query. This is useful sometimes, but it does raise the danger of an injection vulnerability. On the other hand, when you pass a hash of values, like this:

```
 Model.where(event_id: params[:id])
```

...then AR automatically *quotes* the values for you, protecting you against SQL injection.

Comment: Quoting doesn't protect from SQL injection. Using parameterized queries does - as in *real* parameters passed at the DB (ODBC or other) driver level, not writing a SQL script that calls whatever statement execution is used by a DB. The v4 SQL Server adapter at least is susceptible to this bug. With parameterized queries no quoting is necessary

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your comment. The point of my answer is that when you use ActiveRecord's query-building methods as in the second example, it is *supposed* to build a query which has no possibility of SQL injection. If that is not true, you should open a ticket on the ActiveRecord bug tracker.

Comment: Query building is performed by the adapter, not ActiveRecord itself. This particular adapter actually creates a SQL string that declares and assings parameters before executing a dynamic SQL string - moving the point of injection from the query itself to the parameter assignments. This causes interesting failures when end users enter emojis like  or smileys. A simple ODBC call would have avoided the problem and wouldn't even require sanitization or quoting. Which makes me wonder, how do the other adapters handle server calls?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Which internal component of ActiveRecord actually builds the query is not relevant to the OP's question. End users *should* be able to use AR to get data out of a database, without any danger of SQL injection, as long as they use the style recommended in this answer. If that is not true, then the AR bug tracker is the right place to raise the issue, not here.

Comment: Some useful reading on `.order` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859880/is-activerecords-order-method-vulnerable-to-sql-injection

Answer (score 12):

Yes, your code is safely being cleansed before it is run on the database.  Rails protects you from sql injection by automatically sanitizing input.

**THE EXCEPTION** is string interpolation:

```
Guest.where("event_id = #{params[:id]}") # NEVER do this
```

Use one of these 2 options instead:

```
Guest.where(:event_id => params[:id]) # if you want pure ruby, use this
# OR
Guest.where("event_id = ?", params[:id]) # if you prefer raw SQL, use this
```

Check out the [Rails Guide on security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) for more information related to sql injection as well as other common attacks.

Comment: On your 2nd option here, will rails sanitize params[:id]?

Comment: The only real defense against SQL Injection is real parameterized queries. Sanitization can catch only a limited number of cases, while parameterization simply doesn't have this issue - parameters are passed as different pieces of data at the driver (eg ODBC) level, they are never part of the script. Sanitization and quoting are only workarounds

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it would be great to add a link on how to implement parameterized queries with ActiveRecord !

Comment: when using  string interpolation, the sql injection is high

Answer (score 6):

If you really need to use raw sql, you could use [quote](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote) to prevent SQL injection

Here is an example that has been copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34403240/1328513)

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
name = conn.quote("John O'Neil")
title = conn.quote(nil)
query = "INSERT INTO users (name,title) VALUES (#{name}, #{title})"
conn.execute(query)
```