# Is ActiveRecord's “order” method passed with hash vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Adding to the same question from [(HERE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859880/is-activerecords-order-method-vulnerable-to-sql-injection), I am planning to use hash instead of string as parameter. Say,

```
User.order(params[:column].to_sym => params[:direction].to_sym)
```

Where `params[:column]` and `params[:direction]` are passed from the page for sorting the table [(Reference)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns). I even added `.to_sym` to both parameters just so that it will be forced into a symbol instead of string just to be safe (although I am not sure if this is even necessary)

Now, I would just like to know if this approach is safe.

P.S. tried ransack gem, however I couldn't do nested queries. So I wrote my own customizable one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is at least still open for a Denail of Service attack. 
http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/denial_of_service/index.html

The reference is from a nice gem called brakeman which finds vunerable things in a rails application.

In general I would advise you to use @dmcnally's approach from [the other issue you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859880/is-activerecords-order-method-vulnerable-to-sql-injection).

Here an example of what I did in my own projects:

```
SORT = {  newest: { created_at: :desc },
          cheapest: { price: :asc },
          most_expensive: { price: :desc }
}.stringify_keys
```

And then use `SORT[param[:sort]]` to get the sort order. You can also do this by using two seperate hashes for direction and column like you supposed. If you use brakeman you will be able to have a little but of safety since it finds most things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols don't protect you from SQL injection, query parametrization protects you from SQL injection - and this only on the value side, not on the column name side. The thing to take from the other article is "not safe to use interpolated strings in column name when calling .order", not "not safe to use strings when calling .order",

your example defines ordering using a hash - that hash gets translated into a parametrized SQL query in AR, so it is safe as long as you sanitize the column name. One liberal way to do this is to:

```
raise "Unknown column name #{params[:column]}" unless YourModel.column_names.include?(params[:column])
```

PS What .to_sym does in your example is that it enables a third party to define a new symbol on the ruby vm. Symbols are never garbage collected so the attacker can send many different values so that your ruby processes hog the system memory - thus opening you to a ddos attack. The cast in the end does nothing because if you look [here](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/select_manager.rb#L168) you'll notice your value gets cast into string anyway :)

Comment: Ohh so, without .to_sym, will it be safe from SQL injection like: `User.order(params[:column] => params[:direction])` ?

Comment: Aaah, sorry, I did not notice that the column is also param'd, I'll update my answer