# Explain how order clause can be exploited in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

I am having difficulty understanding how this section from [this website on Rails SQL Injections](http://rails-sqli.org/#resources) works.

> Taking advantage of SQL injection in ORDER BY clauses is tricky, but a CASE statement can be used to test other fields, switching the sort column for true or false. While it can take many queries, an attacker can determine the value of the field.

Can someone explain? The bit where they say "switching the sort column for true or false" is the one that is hard to understand because I don't get how that would enable an attacker to reveal the value of another field.

Comment: `switching the sort column for true or false`, means suppose you are calling on User model like `User.order(condition)` in condition you can say as `CASE password WHEN 's' THEN 0 else 1 END` here you are checking for true or false. Your password  case will fail but, else part will return `true` and condition will pass and it will fetch the records. mostly password is saved as `password` field only then this will return the array of user objects with their passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to determine the value of a field you know is in the table, but not being returned in the select you could iterate over it in the order by, until you get the value:

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN variableIdLikeToDiscover < 'N' then 1 else 0 end
```

Then see whether it is greater than or less than 'N'. If it's less than, next you could try:

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN variableIdLikeToDiscover < 'F' then 1 else 0 end
```

And so on and so forth until you have (eventually) determined the value.

Comment: Are the 'N' and 'F' special values or are you saying its a simple character comparison?

Comment: It is a simple character comparison. You can bisect the problem set. Basically, you can ask ANY boolean question, and use the resutling sort to determine the answer. So you can ask "CASE WHEN LEN(thingToDiscover) < 5 then 1 else 0 end" and first figure out how many characters it is. Then you can test character by character using substring. It would be time consuming, but you could hack the value to get a password (if the password was available in one of the joined tables).

Comment: Ah brilliant. Thank you Bill. I am writing code that mitigates the general case of using user input directly into an order clause, and therefore I should expect to be able to describe an attack vector. This was great.

Answer (score 1):

The example shows that the :order parameter will be placed at the end of the statement, so if you add a comparison that is always true at the end, it will update all the rows.

For example, if you make a non-malicious order, it will be like:

```
params[:order] = "name"
User.update_all("admin = 1", "name LIKE 'B%'" , { :order => params[:order] })
```

The generated SQL will be:

```
UPDATE "users" SET admin = 1 WHERE "users"."id" IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (name LIKE 'B%') ORDER BY name))
```

So, the update will be made on the users that have name LIKE 'B%'.

But, when the param is set to:

```
params[:order] = "name) OR 1=1;"
```

The generated SQL will be:

```
UPDATE "users" SET admin = 1 WHERE "users"."id" IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (name LIKE 'B%') ORDER BY name) OR 1=1;)
```

Basically, an OR comparison will be added to the original WHERE, and the comparison will be: Update the users that have name LIKE 'B%' or 1=1. This will cause all the users to be update to admin=1 (in the given example).

Then the attacker can log in with any user an have admin privileges.

Hope it helps...