# Order a model from an associate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that I call "Idee" and I want to order this model by date and popularity (there is a voting system for that). I have followed [this railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=asciicast). And it works but only for the date, the votes are stored in the Vote table, here is my association:

**Vote**

```
belongs_to :idee
belongs_to :user
```

**User** `has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy`

**Idee** `has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy`

And I don't know how can I say that the Idee are order by vote because the count of vote is made on the Vote table and not in Idee so if I said to sort by vote he want to find a column vote in my Idee. So here is what I have done for now :

**Application Helper**

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
   title ||= column.titleize
   direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
   link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
end
```

**Controller**

```
  def publiee
  @idees = Idee.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  @activites = Activite.all
  end

    private
  def sort_column
    params[:sort] || "created_at"
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:direction] || "asc"
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= sortable "created_at", "Date" %>
```

Is there a way to do what I want with what I've done for now ?

PS: My "Idee" are not display in a `<table>`

Answer (score 2):

Do use `joins`.

```
def publiee
  @idees = Idee.order_idess_by_votes sort_column, sort_direction
  @activites = Activite.all
end
```

### Inside the `Idee` model the below code should go

```
scope :order_idess_by_votes, ->(sort_column, direction) { joins(:votes).order("#{order_expr(sort_column, direction)}, COUNT(votes.id) DESC)") }

private 

def order_expr sort_column, direction
  # list all possible columns that you want to use in ORDER clause
  # to SQL
  order_mappings = {
    'first_name_asc'  => 'first_name ASC',
    'first_name_desc' => 'first_name DESC',
    'created_at_asc'  => 'created_at ASC',
    'created_at_desc' => 'created_at DESC',
    # .....
  }

  order_mappings["#{sort_column}_{direction}"]
end
```

Comment: @SimonM. You don't need to change anything inside the view.. It will work.

Comment: be careful, this `.order("#{sort_column}, COUNT(votes.id)  #{sort_direction})"` open vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @Зелёный We can handle it when doing `where`, but with `order` how to do? Any idea ?

Comment: [@ArupRakshit `sort_direction` and `sort_column` come from `params`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859880/is-activerecords-order-method-vulnerable-to-sql-injection) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630381/explain-how-order-clause-can-be-exploited-in-rails)

Comment: @Зелёный nice .. I didn't aware of that.. Thanks

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm a beginner on rails I didn't get everything of your answer but thank you for help, however It still doesn't work, "order_expr" isn't defined

Comment: @SimonM. there will be minor bugs.. that I'll fix with you.. I wrote it by doing only my _imagination_ power. Can you be available [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79959/r-o-r) after 5 hours from now ? I will be then home. I'll try to help you with the understanding..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes of course, I appreciate your help. I will be there, but I still try from myself to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

in `Idee` model class:

```
scope :with_votes_count, -> { select("idees.*, count(votes.id) as votes_count").references(:votes).includes(:votes).group('idees.id') }
```

then in controller:

```
def publiee
  @idees = Idee.with_votes_count.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
  @activites = Activite.all
end

private
def sort_column
  column = params[:sort] || 'created_at'
  Idee.columns.include?(column) ? column : "created_at"
end
```

Now, all you have to do is pass `sort_column` as "`votes_count`" and `sort_direction` as "`DESC`" or "`ASC`" as you wish to make it work.

Comment: Man, I just learned *vulnerable to sql injection* in `ORDER` clause also.. o^0

Comment: @ArupRakshit : Good point, updated the answer accordingly. Thanks buddy.