# Function parameter and different use as a object and SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a function with a parameter and then use this parameter all over my function but I have some issue, I don't know how to convert it for this two different cases

```
def html_append(attribute)
[...].order(attribute: :asc)  [...] 
[...]current_object.attribute[...]
```

Do you have any lead? 
Have a great day.

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

So what you could do here is send the attribute in as a symbol and handle it as follows:

```
def html_append(attribute)
  Post.order(attribute => :asc)
  current_object.public_send(attribute)
end

example_attribute = :name
html_append(example_attribute)
```

This should work just fine, the only thing with public_send is its gives whoever is sending in the attribute access to invoke any of your public methods (send gives then access to invoke all of them) so I would be careful where you are getting this attribute from and have a well thought out public and private interface for this object.

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

For your second example, you can simply do something like this.

```
def html_append(attribute)
  current_object[attribute]
end
```

Using the order method is a bit more complicated. Be careful because it might seem like a good idea to do something like this.

```
def unsafe_method(attribute)
  [...].order("#{attribute} ASC")  [...] 
end
```

The above example would be vulnerable to SQL injection. In an ideal world, you’d be able to do something like this.

```
Model.all.order("? ASC", attribute)
```

But unfortunately that’s not part of the Rails API. As things are, you need to make sure that anything going into `order` is safe to execute against your database. There's a [great answer about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861739/6660632) already.

One simple option would be to have an array of safe attributes which you can validate the argument against. But be careful using this because if the `if` statement is removed, the method is open to SQL injection once again.

```
def safe_method(attribute)
  safe_order_options = ["name", "email", "phone"]
  if attribute.in? safe_order_options
    [...].order("#{attribute} ASC")  [...] 
  end
end
```

And even better option would be this.

```
def safer_method(attribute)
  safe_order_options = ["name", "email", "phone"]
  order_index = safe_order_options.index(attribute)
  [...].order("#{safe_order_options[order_index]} ASC")  [...] 
end
```

Hope that helps. Sorry if there are any typos. I haven't tested this code, but it should work in principle.

Comment: There _is_ a solution for sql injection. Check the other answer.

Comment: That's a good solution, but you still need to be careful where you're getting the attribute from.

Comment: Out of curiousity, do you have an example of a working attack on that form of sorting?

Comment: On the public_send method or my "unsafe" method?

Comment: On the safe method :) `.order(attribute => :asc)`

Comment: I'm no expert in SQL Injection, but try something like this `html_append("(CASE SUBSTR(password, 1, 1) WHEN 's' THEN 0 else 1 END)")`.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. :) The column name is quoted (and quotes are escaped) http://pastie.org/10943025

Comment: The small quotes weren't escaped in my experiment, but it failed anyway because the password field didn't exist in my database. I don't have time to test out every possible SQL injection, but was just following the advice from [rails-sqli.org](http://rails-sqli.org/#order). If you're happy to trust the arguments and the escaped quotes, that's fine. I quite like Dinesh's solution.

Comment: Yes, of course, whitelisting is a very good security measure.

Comment: The examples posted for SQL injection rely on you passing a constructed SQL string  to a query method like `order` or `where` (generally poor form regardless of the Access Layer) when using a `Hash` or `Array` it becomes very similar to a parameterized query and the escaping will be handled for you along with the type conversion.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your help !

Answer (score 0):

What ever you do with attribute It is better to check for column names for security reasons.

```
def html_append(attribute)
  return unless Post.class.column_names.include?(attribute.to_s)
  # Above guard condition will make sure the security of below code
  # your code do public_send(attribute) or send(). You are safe.
end
```