# Rails - SQL injection using .order to filter an index

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my index view, I'm iterating over a list of bookings.

Also, I added a dropdown menu with the option to sort by **created_at: asc** and **created_at: desc**.

## index.html.erb

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Sort by
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
     <p> <%= link_to "ASC", sort: :asc %> </p>
     <p> <%= link_to "DESC", sort: :desc %> </p>
   </div>
 </div>

<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <%= booking.address %>
  <%= booking.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

This is the way I am sorting the **@bookings** in the controller:

## booking_controller.rb

```
class Users::BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bookings = current_user.bookings.order(created_at: params[:sort])
  end
end
```

I'm not really sure if this is the best solution and if it has some vulnerability in terms of SQL injections...

Comment: There are probably a couple of ways to do this, but one is do the sorting by creation date in your controller and store that in `@bookings`. Your controller can get a `params` setting from your view if you want the user to pick the sort order. Don't sort in your view, that's the job of the controller. In your view, use [`collection_select`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) to create a select based upon `@bookings`. The `collection_select` does all the work for you to create a `select` with `option` list.

Comment: What are the benefit of using [collection_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) compared with ```@bookings = current_user.bookings.order(created_at: params[:sort])```?

Comment: Maybe a duplication of this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859880/is-activerecords-order-method-vulnerable-to-sql-injection

Comment: @ElMarco they are two different things. `current_user.bookings.order(created_at: params[:sort])` is how you get the records you want in the order you want. You usually call that in the controller. `collection_select` is what you use in the view show them the way you want to show them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Passing key/value pairs to `order(created_at: params[:sort])` is safe. Rails validates the direction. If you give it an invalid direction it will raise `ArgumentError: Direction "..." is invalid.` It's been this way since [the syntax was introduced in Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/633ea6a826cb5e587165f78d15770271cb39f670).

Passing a string to `order` as in `order("created_at #{params[:sort]}")` could be [exploited in Rails 5 and earlier](https://rails-sqli.org/rails5). See [Rails SQL Injection](https://rails-sqli.org/) for details. Rails 6 now sanitizes `order` arguments and will raise an exception if it detects funny business.

Rails 6, in general, is more robust against SQL injection. But it's up to you to sanitize your inputs before passing them to anything which accepts raw SQL.

---

Your view is not turning the bookings into a drop down menu. Instead, it's just a bunch of text. As [lurker suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463471/rails-sql-injection#comment108726751_61463471), use a function like [`collection_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select) to generate the `select` and `option` tags for you.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :booking_id, @bookings, :id, proc { |b| "#{b.address} #{b.created_at}" , prompt: true %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

To tidy that up a bit, you can add a method to Booking to produce the label you want and replace the `proc`.

```
class Booking
  def dropdown_value
    "#{address} #{created_at}"
  end
end

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :booking_id, @bookings, :id, :dropdown_value, prompt: true %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I haven't tested myself, but it seems that `order` is vulnerable to SQL injection. See: https://rails-sqli.org/

Comment: @Sumak That's only relevant if you pass the arguments as a single string. Key/value is fine. It's a good reminder, thanks. I can't replicate their `order` example in Rails 6.

Comment: @Sumak I see how they're exploiting it now.

Comment: `order` is vulnerable to SQL injections, see https://rails-sqli.org/#order

Comment: @Vlad Only if you pass a string, and that was fixed in Rails 6.

Answer (score 0):

Generally using `params` for `order` is unsafe, see https://rails-sqli.org/#order

You can use [sanitize_sql_for_order](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_order) to sanitaze input for `ActiveRecord#order`

Comment: The problem is only applicable to passing a string to `order`, and only before Rails 6. As far as I can tell, `order(created_at: params[:sort])` is safe.