# Brakeman sql injection warning for string interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I ran brakeman on my software and it has came back with some sql injection warnings. Most of these consist of lines of code that contain string interpolation. Is this is false positive or is there different syntax that can be used to avoid these warnings?

An example of a warning I have is:

```
self.by_searchstr(search).order(arel_table[:id]).joins(:cow).joins(:gender_lookup).order("#{sort_order}")
```

'Message: Possible SQL injection'

It specifically highlights 'sort_order'

I would hope there to be a simple fix for this as I have plenty others exactly like this.

Comment: Quite an old question and it might be out-dated, but I still suggest having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859880/is-activerecords-order-method-vulnerable-to-sql-injection

Comment: this should fix the error: `self.by_searchstr(search).order(arel_table[:id]).joins(:cow).joins(:gender_lookup).order(sort_order)`

Comment: Thank you,  but what about in scenarios such as  `order("animal.known_deceased ASC, #{sort}, animal.id")`, does the same principle apply or how should this be dealt with. This too provides an sql injection error.

Comment: Whats the use case? Why does this need to take a string in the first place?

Comment: Hi max, this query is used to perform a search on an animals search string. When a user searches and the method that contains this is ran, an active record relation will be found. To the answer to your second question. I'm not sure.

Comment: Newer versions of Rails (definitely 7.0+) [handle `order` arguments in a safer manner](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order), preventing arbitrary SQL. However, allowing the user to control the column can allow attackers to probe what (or how many) columns exist. This may or may not be a security concern, depending on the tables.

Comment: Just as clarification, passing in as '.order(sort_order)', instead of using string interpolation, is there any drawbacks to this? Is there other benefits of using string interpolation?

Answer (score 2):

`order` can be called with a list of symbols:

```
order(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

You can compose and whitelist this list as an array and use the splat operator to convert arrays into a list:

```
order(*whitelisted_columns)
```

Or a hash where the keys are the columns and the values are the direction:

```
order(foo: :asc, bar: :desc, baz: :asc)
```

This isn't an actual keyword argument so you don't need to use a double splat if you call it with a pre-composed hash.

```
orderings = { foo: :asc, bar: :desc, baz: :asc }.slice(*whitelist)
order(orderings)
```

You can also use a combination of both list and hash arguments.

```
order(:foo, { bar: :asc, baz: :desc})
```

If you are taking this as user input you should whitelist both the names of the columns and the direction.

Calling order with a SQL string or Arel should only be done if you completely trust the inputs and if the job actually requires it.

Comment: If you have to take the input as a SQL string like `foo desc, bar asc` you should first deconstruct it and whitelist each part and then use it to construct a hash that you pass to `order`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes it more digestible in terms of understanding.